# ldappasswd with RootDN bind not working

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to change password for user `jdoe` using `ldappasswd` via RootDN bind. Executed command looks like

```
ldappasswd -H ldap://10.12.21.10 -x -D "CN=ldap_manager,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local" -w ldap_manager_pswd -s newpasswd "CN=Jane Doe,DC=mycompany,DC=local"
```

but it throws an error

> Result: Protocol error (2) 
>   Additional info: 0000203D: LdapErr: DSID-0C090DA1, comment: Unknown extended request OID, data 0, v1db1

Bind works fine as I can execute `ldapsearch`

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://10.12.21.10 -x -D "CN=ldap_manager,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local" -w ldap_manager_pswd "CN=Jane Doe"
```

Any tips what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few thoughts:

- Does jdoe's collection of object classes support the field userPassword?
- Do you have a password policy, which needs you to enter the old password when changing to a new one?
- Is CN=ldap_manager,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local allowed (via access rules) to view and/or change userPassword fields (for the user)?

Curious about your thoughts on these points!

**EDIT:**

Do you use AD or OpenLDAP? Please check whether the version of software you use supports the LDAP Password Modify Extended Operation (see RFC 3062). I heard that some versions of AD do not support them.

Comment: I'm on AD and it looks like I'm on that one which doesn't support password change. Had try to use code directly via AD machine and via Samba - nothing works

Comment: Can't you just use the `ldapmodify` instead?

Comment: Yes - cannot get it to work. What I have got to work it was `dsmod user %arg1% -pwd %arg2%` directly on AD machine but I had no luck to get this to work without elevated command prompt exectuion